# How to pick a type from a nested object?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a type Student with a relation to Grade (A student can have many grades):

```
export interface Student {
    id: number,
    name: string
    surname: string
    age: number
    email: string
    Grades: List<Grade>
}
```

I want to only pick the keys of the Object that is of type `List<any>`, I wrote a type for that:

```
export type Filter<T, Condition> = {
    // Set all types that match the Condition to the value of the field (i.e. name: "name")
    // Else set the type to never
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Condition ? K : never 
}[keyof T] // Selects all the types of all the keys except for never
```

`Filter<Student, List<any>>` results in the type: `"Grades"`.

The next stepp is to get from `"Grades"` to just the type `Grade`.

I have tried the following:

`Student["Grades"]` but that results in the type `List<Grade>`.

**Is there a way to only get the inner type?**

Comment: If the `List` is an `Array`, you could go with just `Student['Grades'][number]`

Comment: I tried that, but the List is not an `Array` it is a custum linkedlist. I have to use that because it is a homework question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) to grab the generic parameter of a generic type, like this:

```
type ListType<T> = T extends List<infer U> ? U : never;
```

And you can use it like this:

```
let grade: ListType<Student["Grades"]> // inferred type Grade
```

Or using your `Filter`, like this:

```
let grade: ListType<Student[Filter<Student, List<any>>]> // inferred type Grade
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed